# Prevent vim-go plugin from calling 'less' on save

Tags: vim, go

I am playing around with the "Go" programming language and using Vim with the vim-go plugin. Every time I save, this plugin seems to pipe the contents of the file to less and this gets really annoying as the file becomes larger. Even putting a `!` after the `w` is not helping. Pressing Q removes the 'less' part which removes the need to hold in the enter key til the end of the file is reached but I don't want to keep doing that.

Anyone using this plugin and knows a way to prevent 'less' from being called on save?

Comment: I'm also using vim-go and `less` is not executed on save. Can you share some related configuration? Also try to play with `g:go_fmt_command`, `g:go_fmt_fail_silently` and `g:go_fmt_autosave`. See the [github repo](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) for information on the options

Comment: Thanks. `let g:go_fmt_fail_silently = 1` and `let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0` seem to have done the trick. When I test each one separately, both work independently. But I just added them both because I have nothing to loosse. Just playing with the language. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you share what you use as operating system, Vim version and an example demo file? I would be happy to debug it more as I and many others don't see this errors. Here is an open case: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/217 If you can participate there I would be happy :)

Answer (score 1):

`let g:go_fmt_fail_silently = 1` and `let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0` seem to have done the trick. When I test each one separately, both work independently. But I just added them both because I have nothing to loosse. Just playing with the language.
                    – Touch